How to force remove (not hide) a third party icon from menu bar
I have searched and tried many ways but none of them satisfied me.

Hold command key and drag them out the menu bar. It shows a circle with a line through so cannot be removed.
Use App setting. It lacks the setting for hiding icon in menu bar (poorly designed app).
Use Bartender or Hidden Bar/Dozer. It hides icons like "folding" them and gives me a new arrow icon, which I don't like. (If any app can remove icon instead of folding them, I'd like to use).

Maybe there is a way to delete or modify a file in /Library or some place, so the icon of an app can be removed?
PS. The App which I want to remove its icon is WeChat.

I would contact the developers for support.

You can actually hide any icon in Bartender 5 (paid app) including the "fold" icon which is 3 dots. If you want to hide the "fold" icon:

Open Bartender 5
Go to Menu Bar Items option tab.
Drag & Drop the "fold" icon ( the triple dots ) from Shown menu bar items tray to Always Hidden menu bar items

Here's a screenshot for reference:


Thank you. But it seems Bartender is not free. Maybe I'll try later.

Paying to Hide the problem, rather than fixing it for free seems a bit non-optimal.
